# howto firebird transpose string distinct row to column

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

My DB Structure

```
Doccode | Em_Name

AAAA1   |   John
BBB15   |   Vivi
CCC12   |   Ronaldo
AAAA1   |   Michelle
```

i want to result like this

```
Doccode | Em_Name

AAAA1   |   John, Michelle <---- distinct data will show in the same row
BBB15   |   Vivi
CCC12   |  Ronaldo
```

what is command to do that in firebird?

Answer (score 4):

In more recent versions of Firebird, you can do this with the [`list()`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-aggrfunc-list.html) function:

```
select doccode, list(em_name, ', ') as em_names
from table t
group by doccode;
```

Comment: i just want to ask whether `GROUP_CONCAT` will work here or not?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . `group_concat()` is available in MySQL and SQLite.  The equivalent in Firebird is `list()`.

Comment: For distinct values you need to use `LIST(DISTINCT em_name, ', ')`